# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly using with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hello I got this when I  tired to run the MySQL in XAMPP:

```
12:24:00 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:24:00 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:24:00 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:24:00 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:24:00 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:24:00 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

The log says this:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 423060; transaction id 824
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-11  0:22:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I have seen all the other posts about this issue but none of them relate to my situation. I'm a bit confused why that is the latest log, as the time is different from when I tried to run the MySQL, also I don't see a clear error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In tgat case you have to reinstall xampp. Many times happens. When its asked, dont delete your htdocs folder. If you do not want to waste time because it installs too slowly, desactivate your antivirus while installing and then activate it again